# Can I pass System.Net.SocketAddress type for Xamarin Binding project for sockaddr Objective-C type?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Am writing a Xamarin Binding project for a ObjectiveC static library.As part of the one method I was supposed to pass sockaddr type parameter. But I would like to use System.Net.SocketAddress. Is it valid to pass socketaddress reference to Xamarin Binding project method as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this.

You would need to create a real sockaddr.

Comment: Hi Miguel,great to see you here sir. I am using the PInvoke sockaddr_in definition in my binding project.Am creating an instance for sockaddr_in structure and using Marshall.alloc am getting the pointer to that structure and passing this IntPtr as input in my Apidefinitions.cs file.Is it a correct approach? Here is the error am getting with this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671149/lwip-connect-invalid-address-failed-error